Persisting useActionData After URL Updates in Remix
I am using actions to get some form data in my component. However, this data from useActionData is not getting persisted in the component when I set a new searchParams using the setSearchParams through a button. I would like the actionData to stay even after param addition. In the document it is mentioned that useActionData will return the value of the most recent post request. But i see here that it is getting reset. I would like to know what are the conditions in which useActionData resets.
In this case if I want to persist the data, would it be okay to persist the actionData using setState or setting the response from actions in urlParams itself?
Example code (this is just a sample code to recreate the scenario):
import { json, type LoaderArgs, type ActionArgs } from '@remix-run/node';
import {
  useActionData,
  useLoaderData,
  useSearchParams,
} from '@remix-run/react';

// Simulate data fetching based on a parameter
const fetchData = async (param: string | null) => {
  return param ? [`Data fetched for ${param}`] : ['Default data'];
};

// Loader: Fetch data based on URL search params
export const loader = async ({ request }: LoaderArgs) => {
  const url = new URL(request.url);
  const param = url.searchParams.get('param');

  const data = await fetchData(param);
  return json({ data, param });
};

// Action: Handle form submission and provide data for updating search params
export const action = async ({ request }: ActionArgs) => {
  const formData = await request.formData();
  const input = formData.get('param')?.toString() || '';

  if (!input) {
    return json({ error: 'Input cannot be empty' }, { status: 400 });
  }

  // Return data to the component for use in setting the params
  return json({ param: input });
};

// Component
const ExamplePage = () => {
  const loaderData = useLoaderData<typeof loader>();
  const actionData = useActionData<typeof action>();
  const [searchParams, setSearchParams] = useSearchParams();

  console.log('action data:', actionData);

  // Function to set a random value in the URL param
  const setRandomParam = () => {
    const randomValue = Math.random().toString(36).substring(2, 8); // Generate a random string
    setSearchParams({ param: randomValue });
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Example Page</h1>
      <p>
        Current Param: <strong>{loaderData.param || 'none'}</strong>
      </p>
      <p>Fetched Data:</p>
      <ul>
        {loaderData.data.map((item, index) => (
          <li key={index}>{item}</li>
        ))}
      </ul>

      <form method="post">
        <label>
          Enter Param:
          <input type="text" name="param" />
        </label>
        <button type="submit">Submit</button>
      </form>

      {/* Button to update the URL with a random value */}
      <button onClick={setRandomParam}>Set Random Param</button>
    </div>
  );
};

export default ExamplePage;

Submit form with "1234567" as input.
Console shows action data: 1234567
Click the button to set random param value. Console shows action data: undefined
